# How to create a pairs. csv file given an image dataset

Tags: python, csv

Given a dataset of images, I would like to create a pairs.csv file for both train and test set. The format for the csv file is shown below

Let's assume in train set folder A contains the following images:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

then my CSV file will look like

```
|ImgA|ImgB
|1.jpg|2.jpg
|1.jpg|3.jpg
|2.jpg|1.jpg
|2.jpg|3.jpg
|3.jpg|1.jpg
|3.jpg|2.jpg
```

Another example of the dataset and csv file structure is shown below.

For the folder structure shown here

[image: folder structure]

some of the csv file entries are as follows:

[image: CSV FOrmat expected sample output]

I could do it manually if the number of images and permutations involved were not that large.
For example, the screenshots were taken from a folder which has 31 subdirectories each subdirectory contains at most 5 or 6 images similar to screenshot 2.

Comment: use `ìtertools.product` and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ìtertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to make the pairings. Here an example of the logic:

```
import itertools as it

# just to make runnable data as string and then splitted into list
data = """1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg"""
data_list = data.split('\n')

# body of the program
header = '|ImgA|ImgB\n'
# make all parings
out = (f'{i}|{j}' for i, j in it.product(data_list, repeat=2) if i!=j)
out = header + '|{}'.format('\n|'.join(out))
print(out)
```

Output

```
|ImgA|ImgB
|1.jpg|2.jpg
|1.jpg|3.jpg
|2.jpg|1.jpg
|2.jpg|3.jpg
|3.jpg|1.jpg
|3.jpg|2.jpg
```

EDIT

- Get the directories

```
data_list = [d for d in os.listdir(path) if d.endswith('.jpg')]
```

- Save the file in current working directory

```
with open('pairs.csv', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(out)
```

Edit 2:

from the comments: if amount of image big, 52712, `itertools.product` (or the generator) seems to "crash". Here (hope) another way with an explicit `for`-loop:

```
with open('...', 'w') as wd:
    header = '|ImgA|ImgB\n'
    fd.write(header)
    try:
        for i, j in it.product(data_list, repeat=2):
            if i != j:
                fd.write(f'|{i}|{j}\n')            
    except Exception("No way... to many data, a new strategy should be found!!") as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: thanks ,if i wanted to write it to csv,should I simply do csv.writer()
where data  is i followed by j

Comment: itertools is causing the colab session to crash,not sure if it can be done on my system alsoThe total number of images in directory is 52712

Comment: amount of combiantions `print(2**52712)`... it is a number with 15868 digits:) I will edit a new implementation... but I don't garantuee

Comment: I know,
acutally I wrote this implementation
```
for i in range(len(data_list)):
  for j in range(len(data_list)):
    if(i!=j):
      with open('pairs.csv','w') as fp:
        fp.write(data_list[i])
```
IIt is working but it only writes one line at a time . I have also enclosed  new screenshot that shows what is my expected output like.

Comment: bad idea! you put the `with` statement inside the loop!!! it will be opened "2**52712"-times! just do once as I did in the Edit 2 answer

Comment: ok will try it and let you know
also,will using itertools.permutations help in this case

Comment: permutation is factorial, power is an exponential base 2. factorial >>>>> exponential.

Comment: the current implementation is now causing the disk space to run out

Comment: which current implementation? factorial? well I don't know how much space you have on the disk... but I warn you that you are dealing with file which amount of lines is  a number  with 15000 digits! Try to get an estimation of the required space... amount of character per line x character storage x amount of lines and expressed in scientific notation to get an idea of the scala (mega, giga, ...)

Comment: @Sparsh Garg try with 20-lines, `[d for d in os.listdir(path) if d.endswith('.jpg')]`[:20]`, to understand the size of the file

Comment: actually if i use your suggested line  data_list comes out to be 0.I have encllosed screenshot that shows dataset strucutre as well as my own additions.

Comment: it could be that the path of the images and the one of the python program are differents